# what is wrong with this if else statment

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to add some text to an html element by its ID randomly changing between a few different cases for different visitors.

For some reason,  my text is not being added to the element.

Anyone see whats wrong with my code?

Here is a link to a JSBin thing i set up.

http://jsbin.com/biresocera/1/edit

```html
<script>
    var linkAnchor = $('#link-anchor');
    var randShareLink = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) + 1;

    $(document).ready(function(){
        if (randShareLink === 1){
            $(linkAnchor).append('case 1');
        } else if (randShareLink === 2){
            $(linkAnchor).append('case 2');
        } else {
            $(linkAnchor).append('case 3');
        }
    });
</script>

<body>
 <div id="link-anchor" style="background-color:red; height:40px; color:white; width:50px;"></div> 
</body>
```

Comment: you have closing paren at end with no opening one to go with it

Comment: linkAnchor is already a jQuery object. No need for `$(linkAnchor)`. Just `linkAnchor.append()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is fine. However, your jsbin is not set up correctly - you need to add the jquery library to make it work.

Also, use linkAnchor.append, as it is already a jquery object.

http://jsbin.com/zokedozibe/1/edit

Answer (score 0):

Missing JQuery framework

```js
var linkAnchor = $('#link-anchor');
var randShareLink = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) + 1;

$(document).ready(function(){
    if (randShareLink === 1){
        $(linkAnchor).append('case 1');
    } else if (randShareLink === 2){
        $(linkAnchor).append('case 2');
    } else {
        $(linkAnchor).append('case 3');
    }
});
```

```html
<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
</head>

<body>
 <div id="link-anchor" style="background-color:red; height:40px; color:white; width:50px;"></div> 
</body>
```

http://jsbin.com/biqovedeqe/1/